# HTML5 Canvas - draw the same thing in all canvas elements by class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have the following HTML...

```
<body onload="draw();">

  <p><a href=""><canvas class="demo2" width="6" height="12">Fallback</canvas> Back to (1)...</a></p>
  <p><a href=""><canvas class="demo2" width="6" height="12">Fallback</canvas> Back to (2)...</a></p>

</body>
```

...and javascript:

```
function draw() {        
    var canvas2 = $('.demo2').get(0); // This draws in the first canvas
    //var canvas2 = $('.demo2').get(); This doesn't draw at all
    if (canvas2.getContext) {
        var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');

        ctx2.beginPath();
        ctx2.moveTo(6,0);
        ctx2.lineTo(6,12);
        ctx2.lineTo(0,6);
        ctx2.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,100,220)';
        ctx2.fill();
    }
}
```

What I'd like to happen is for the all canvases with the class `demo2` to be drawn in.

I thought `$('.demo2').get()` would get all elements by that classname. `$('.demo2').get(0)` draws in the first one but I'd like to draw in them all.

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/kMN3s/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.each` to execute things for each `.demo2`: http://jsfiddle.net/kMN3s/2/.

```
function draw() {        
    $('.demo2').each(function() {
        if (this.getContext) { // `this` is an element each time
            var ctx2 = this.getContext('2d');

            ctx2.beginPath();
            ctx2.moveTo(6,0);
            ctx2.lineTo(6,12);
            ctx2.lineTo(0,6);
            ctx2.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,100,220)';
            ctx2.fill();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated your demo http://jsfiddle.net/kMN3s/1/

```
$('canvas.demo2').each(function() { }
```

Comment: +1 That's great, thanks. @pimvdb got there just before you though so I'm giving the 'accepted' to him.